# Nextflow - cannot get access to the variable at publishDir

Tags: scripting, nextflow

I have a pipeline with two processes. I want to pass the results files of the first process used by the second process and save the output files in a separate directory for each of the files:

```
process one {
.
.

    output:
    file "split.*.json" into groups
.
.

}

process two {
.
.
    publishDir params.output_path + "/exec_logs/train/${split.baseName}", mode: 'copy'


    input:
    set split from groups.flatten()

    output:
    file ".command.out"
    file ".command.err"
.
.
    """
    echo $split
    """
}
```

When I try the run the pipeline I get the following error:
`No such variable: split` in the `publishDir ...` line, but I have access to the split variable in the run section.

How can I get access to the split variable in the publishDir?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is actually the string concatenation. Try supplying instead a single GString:

```
publishDir "${params.output_path}/exec_logs/train/${split.baseName}", mode: 'copy'
```

For the example above, ensure also that the 'split' variable is provided using the [`path`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#input-of-type-path) qualifier:

```
input:
path split from groups.flatten()
```